# Create Table in Big Query

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a csv file and I am trying to create a table in BQ.

But every time I click "Auto Detect" (Schema) and "Create Table" it makes both columns into integer.
I want one column as string and one column as integer.

For example it gives me the result as (Both Columns are integer):

[image]

But I want the result as (String):
Even though I have saved the xls as this when I save the file as csv it eliminated the zeros infront.

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

From the BigQuery document

> When auto-detection is enabled, BigQuery starts the inference process
>   by selecting a random file in the data source and scanning up to 100
>   rows of data to use as a representative sample. BigQuery then examines
>   each field and attempts to assign a data type to that field based on
>   the values in the sample.

BigQuery purely uses the value to infer the schema, so the best solution for the problem is passing the schema explicitly.

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/schema-detect

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the schema explicitly and set the `autodetect` schema as `False`.

1. https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/schema-detect
2. https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-cloud-storage-csv